# Circular Prime Numbers without sieve algorithm or libraries in Python

Tags: python

> The number, 197, is called a circular prime because all rotations of the digits: 197, 971, and 719, are themselves prime.
>
> There are thirteen such primes below 100: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 31, 37, 71, 73, 79, and 97.
>
> How many circular primes are there below one million?

I'm trying to do [Project Euler #35](https://projecteuler.net/problem=35) and am having trouble coming up with a solution that doesn't implement any outside libraries or sieves algorithms.

Trying to keep it as basic as possible, I created a few functions to rotate a number and check if it's prime. I'm having data type issues once I try combining the two functions and I'm having trouble managing my data types between ints and strs as they relate to the list object I'm using to store each rotation.

My code:

```
def is_prime(n):
    m = int(n)
    for i in range(2,m-1):
            if (m%i) == 0:
                    return False
    return (True if m>1 else False)

def rotate(n):
    list = []
    string = str(n)
    for i in string:
        front = string[0]
        rest = string[1:]
        complete = rest + front
        list.append(complete)
        string = complete
    return list 

def rotations(num):
  numString = str(num)
  counter = 0 
  while counter < len(numString): 
    for i in numString:
      rotater = rotate(i)
      if is_prime(rotater) in numString == True: 
        counter+=1 
  return counter

print(rotations(1000))
```

As is, it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/785402618/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(rotations(1000))
  File "/tmp/785402618/main.py", line 25, in rotations
    if is_prime(rotater) in numString == True: 
  File "/tmp/785402618/main.py", line 2, in is_prime
    m = int(n)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. What's your question?

Comment: `is_prime(rotater)` returns `True`/`False`. What is `if is_prime(rotater) in numString == True:` supposed to be checking?

Comment: As @Carcigenicate said, it has no sense to evaluete if `Boolean in Boolean`as parts of the `in` comparation returns `True/False`.

Comment: You can find some more answers looking for "python rotate string". For project euler, it's a good idea to figure out the math yourself. Usually it's about finding a more efficient way. Right now you are going to be checking is_prime too much, and it's not the most efficient, either.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going back and forth between strings and integers, it is easier (and faster) to work solely in integers. Extract the last digit from a number by taking it mod 10. Keep the rest of the digits using integer division by 10. Raise the last digit to the appropriate power of 10 (take the logarithm of the remaining digits) and add it to the remaining digits. That gives you a rotation of the original number.

Your `is_prime` function could be improved by stopping the loop when you pass the square root of *n*. If *n* is composite, at least one of its factors must be less than or equal to its square root; for instance, if *n* = *p* × *q*, then either *p* and *q* are equal to the square root, or one of them is less than the square root and the other is greater.

I'll leave it to you to reduce these ideas to code.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple the digits, add the digits, get the number of digits. Store the associated triple of results as a string. Compare the results then for every string.

```
E.g:   137 maps to "(21, 11, 3)" 
       173 maps to "(21, 11, 3)"
```

Then you just get the index for each string from an array A where the index is the prime number.

```
 j = 0;
 For or while loop:
      j = A.indexOf(someString, j+1);
```

For index j you want the next occurrence of the someString.